# Не работает создание нового объекта на базе существующего (new obj)

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты

Приветствую, есть объект и мне нужно на базе его создать еще 3 передавая в них разные параметры, соответственно выдавать эти объекты будут тоже разные параметры.

Вот мой не рабочий [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/1upduyq2/).

```
    var names = ['Вася','Петя','Гриша'], objs = [];

    var foo = {
        bar : function(name){
            this.name = name;
        },
        baz : function(){
            console.log('Ваше ммя: ' + this.name);
        }
    };

    for(var i in names) 
        objs[ i ] = new foo;
        objs[ i ].bar( names[ i ] );

    for(i in objs)
        $('#names').append('<li>' + objs[ i ].baz() + '</li>');
```

Comment: И не должно работать. Где вы такой способ вообще увидели?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я написал пример, что мне по сути нужно. Как мне решить его со встроенными классами Сможете что-то подсказать? Спасибо

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спасибо большое, прочитал и всё получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью [Павла Майорова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557687/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-new-obj#comment722403_557687), который предоставил [ссылку на ресурс Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), я решил свою проблему.

Вот следующий [код](https://jsfiddle.net/OLDIN_/1upduyq2/1/):

```
var names = ['Вася','Петя','Гриша'], objs = [];

var foo = {
    bar : function(name){
        this.name = name;
    },
    baz : function(){
        return 'Ваше ммя: ' + this.name;
    }
};

for(var i in names){
    objs[ i ] = Object.create( foo, {
      name : { 
        value: names[ i ]
      }
    });
}

for(var i in objs)
    //console.log( objs[ i ].baz() );
    $('#names').append('<li>' + objs[ i ].baz() + '</li>');
```